# Reverse of Porter Stemming Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

By Porter Algorithm, the stem of the word:

- `computer`
- `compute`,
- `computation`

  is `comput`.

I want to know if there exists an algorithm that performs the reverse of Porter Algorithm.
That is, given a stem `comput`, how to find all the words with stem `comput`?

Comment: Do you have a sorted word list?

Comment: no, I don't have a word list

Comment: What is a `word`, then? If there is no criteria, then there is an infinite number of words (like `computaaaaaaaaaaa` and `computaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`).

Comment: You are going to need a dictionary (word list) in order to do that

Comment: There's no algorithm can give you this, language is not logically extended from core roots

Comment: Thanks all. Just downloaded a large word list :)